# why folder.getDeletedMessageCount() always returning -1?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get the details of no.of messages, no.of deleted messages and no.of total messages using javamail api in android. But i am always getting -1 for no.of deleted messages. I couldn't find what is the reason/bug is so please help me with this. Here is my code
    class Readmails extends AsyncTask{

```
    Folder inbox;
    Folder inbox2;
     Properties props = System.getProperties();


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
         try
         {
         /*  Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */
         Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
         Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
         store.connect("imap.gmail.com","test123@gmail.com", "testmycode12345");

         /*  Mention the folder name which you want to read. */
         inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");

         System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());
         System.out.println("No of New Messages : " +    inbox.getNewMessageCount());
         System.out.println("No of Deleted Messages : " +inbox.getDeletedMessageCount());
         System.out.println("No of total  Messages : " + inbox.getMessageCount());
         System.out.println("No of Type Messages : " + inbox.getType());
         /*Open the inbox using store.*/
         inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);



         /*  Get the messages which is unread in the Inbox*/
         Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));

         /* Use a suitable FetchProfile    */
         FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
         fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
         fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
         inbox.fetch(messages, fp);

         try
         {
         inbox.close(true);
         store.close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         System.out.println("Exception arise at the time of read mail");
         ex.printStackTrace();
         }
         }
         catch (NoSuchProviderException e)
         {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(1);
         }
         catch (MessagingException e)
         {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(2);
         }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `getDeletedMessageCount()` before you open the inbox.

See [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/source/browse/trunk/mail/src/java/javax/mail/Folder.java#784) in the code, it says it returns -1 on closed folders.  Move your call to `inbox.open()` above your `println`'s

Comment: It says the same thing [in the javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#getDeletedMessageCount()).  Why does no one read the javadocs anymore?

Comment: Now i am getting 0 first time and deleted a message in server for testing but it returning 0. it is not giving as 1 and i tested 2nd time by deleting another message again it is returning 0.